# Axes at Zero in TikZ Plot

Tags: pgfplots

How would I make it so that I get vertical and horizontal axes at 0 in the chart created below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [data cs=polar,domain=0:360] (\x,1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: Why don't you simply `\usepackage{pgfplots}` instead of RequirePackage (which is intended for packages and classes)?

Answer (score 3):

`axis lines=center` does that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      enlargelimits % maybe you want this as well
    ]
    \addplot+ [data cs=polar,domain=0:360] (\x,1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```